# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'User' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a jail command which when you say a!jail (ping) (integer which is time in minutes) would give the pinged member a role which lets the access only one channel.
Everything is finished on the discord server-side.

The code:

```
import time
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_TOKEN = "hahasikeyouwontgetm"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="a!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0

    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")

        guild_count = guild_count + 1

    print("AnythingBot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")


@client.command()
async def order(ctx, arg):
    if arg == "burger":
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="here burger",
            color=ctx.author.color
        )
        embed.set_image(url='https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/839166049755856906/839166099336593428/burger.jpg'
                            '?width=670&height=670'
                        )
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)


@client.command()
async def math(ctx, arg, arg2, arg3):
    mathed = 0
    answer = 0
    if arg2 == "+":
        answer = float(arg) + float(arg3)
        mathed = 1
    elif arg2 == "-":
        answer = float(arg) - float(arg3)
        mathed = 1
    elif arg2 == "/":
        answer = float(arg) / float(arg3)
        mathed = 1
    elif arg2 == "*":
        answer = float(arg) * float(arg3)
        mathed = 1
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="The answer is: " + str(answer),
        color=ctx.author.color
    )
    if mathed == 1:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)


@client.command()
async def jail(ctx, arg, arg2):
    jailtime = int(arg2) * 60
    arg = arg.replace("<@!", "")
    arg = arg.replace(">", "")
    prisoner = await client.fetch_user(user_id=arg)
    isadmin = False
    admin = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Admin')
    default = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Member')
    jailed = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Jailed')

    embedj = discord.Embed(
        title="Jailed " + prisoner.display_name + " for " + str(jailtime) + "m.",
        color=ctx.author.color
    )

    embedn = discord.Embed(
        title="You must be a staff member to use this command.",
        color=ctx.author.color,
        author="loser"
    )

    embedu = discord.Embed(
        title=prisoner.display_name + " has been unjailed.",
        color=ctx.author.color
    )

    if admin in ctx.message.author.roles:
        if admin in prisoner:
            isadmin = True

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedj)
        await client.add_roles(jailed)

        time.sleep(jailtime)

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedu)

        if isadmin:
            await client.add_roles(prisoner, admin)
        await client.add_roles(prisoner, default)
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedn)


client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\domas\Downloads\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/domas/Downloads/DiscordBot/main.py", line 87, in jail
    if admin in prisoner:
TypeError: argument of type 'User' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\domas\Downloads\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\domas\Downloads\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\domas\Downloads\DiscordBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'User' is not iterable
```

The second one is:

Everything else seems to have worked,  I am confused.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code I have some suggestions in place:

- I suggest using `commands.MemberConverter` instead to make this much easier.
- The error you gave means that `prisoner` cannot be iterated. You will need to get its `.roles` to iterate for admin role.
- You cannot add roles to a user via `client.add_roles`. You need to do it with `discord.Member.add_roles()` instead.
- Instead of using `time.sleep` use `await asyncio.sleep`. Much better practice for asynchronous programs. It might also prevent the bot from working other commands. Make sure to import asyncio though.

Here is the implementation for the jail command (I hope you can use these suggestions to implement for the rest of your commands)

```py
@client.command()
async def jail(ctx, prisoner:commands.MemberConverter, arg2:int):
    jailtime = arg2 * 60
    isadmin = False
    admin = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Admin')
    default = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Member')
    jailed = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Jailed')

    embedj = discord.Embed(
        title="Jailed " + prisoner.display_name + " for " + str(jailtime) + "m.",
        color=ctx.author.color
    )

    embedn = discord.Embed(
        title="You must be a staff member to use this command.",
        color=ctx.author.color,
        author="loser"
    )

    embedu = discord.Embed(
        title=prisoner.display_name + " has been unjailed.",
        color=ctx.author.color
    )

    if admin in ctx.message.author.roles:
        if admin in prisoner.roles:
            isadmin = True

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedj)
        await prisoner.add_roles(jailed) # I wasn't sure exactly what you wanted here, so I just added the jailed role to the prisoner.

        await asyncio.sleep(jailtime)

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedu)

        if isadmin:
            await prisoner.add_roles(admin)
        await prisoner.add_roles(default)
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedn)
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know how I could fix the ```Unresolved attribute reference 'add_roles' for class 'Bot' ``` error?

Comment: You can't add_roles to the bot instance. Do `client.user.add_roles` instead @StarFoxo

Comment: It seems I have said Thanks too early, ```prisoner.roles``` gives me the error: ```Unresolved attribute reference 'roles' for class 'User' ```, I am new when it comes to discord.py

Comment: Oh oops. My mistake. First, you need to change how you used `add_roles`. You need to do `await prisonor.add_roles(*roles)` replacing roles with the role you want to add to prisoner.

Comment: same issue ```Unresolved attribute reference 'add_roles' for class 'User'```

Comment: and ```if admin in prisoner.roles:``` gives the error ```Unresolved attribute reference 'roles' for class 'User' ```

Comment: ah, lemme edit my answer so that I don't have to explain in short snippets. Give me some time.

Comment: @StarFoxo I fixed it, sorry i was preoccupied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `in` if the `prisoner` is only one `discord.User` object. A list would work